# Is the Pandemic expansion "In the Lab" available in multiple languages?

Tags: pandemic

I like to play Pandemic. I have bought the game and the expansion "On the Brink" in Dutch.
Is the expansion "In the Lab" available in multiple languages? Even in Dutch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the versions listed on BGG, it appears there's no Dutch version:
https://boardgamegeek.com/browse/boardgameversion?linked_src_objecttype=thing&linked_src_objectid=137136

Also, I haven't found a Dutch version for this on several Belgian and Dutch web shops.

(On a side note: the Dutch version of Pandemic has some textual errors on the role cards. Just in case you didn't know.)

Comment: Really? Amazing community over there, enjoy!

Comment: There is indeed no Dutch version of "in the Lab". I often found that Dutch versions of boardgames have textual errors, wrong translations or are non-existent.
boardgamegeek is the best website on the internet. Join; you won't regret it ;-)

Comment: Update: A Dutch version of In the Lab became available a few months ago. (A little late if you ask me)

Answer (score 1):

According to [BGG](https://boardgamegeek.com/boardgameexpansion/137136/pandemic-lab#versions), there are multiple language versions, but not in Dutch...

[image: versions]